# How can I get Aspell to check accented characters?

Tags: spelling

I've installed aspell with Homebrew and I've added the italian dictionary. 
Unfortunately aspell don't check words like "è", "necessità" because they are written in this way: "necessit\`a". How can I solve this problem? I launch aspell with:

```
aspell check capitolo1.tex --lang=it --mode=tex
```

Comment: Can you (a) replace all occurrences of `\\`a` with `à`, of `\\`e` with `è`, etc and (b) issue the commands `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to enable direct typesetting of lots of accented characters? Or is there a deeper reason for not using accented characters in your input file directly?